# Was there an Apple IIc clone other than the one from V-Tech?

Tags: apple-ii

When I was a kid, my aunt had an "official" `Laser 128` that was made, IIRC, by V-Tech.

Later in life, I bought a "Laser 128" off eBay but I don't know if it was really from V-Tech or not.  Even though it actually does say "Laser 128" on the case.  But it's not embossed or appears to be high quality printing.

I have never taken it apart to see what the branding on the motherboard is but the whole computer feels like a "clone of a clone".

Is it possible that I have another brand of Laser 128 other than V-Tech or, perhaps, I have a cheaper cost-reduced run made by V-Tech?

I don't have the computer near me at the moment.  But I can dig it up and post pictures if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Is it particular about the Apple II**c**? Because there are numerous Apple II clones from various companies out there.

Comment: Right.  I know there were other II clones.  But I'm only aware of V-Tech making IIc clones.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Franklin Ace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Electronic_Publishers#Early_history) series was a number of Apple II clones.  The Ace 500 specifically was considered a clone of the Apple IIc. You might be interested in [wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_series#Clones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_series#Clones).

As far as I know, there was no relationship between V-Tech and Franklin that would have led to an Ace motherboard in a Laser case.

Comment: Franklin Ace units sold in Sears department stores where I lived included the Spectrum Holobyte GATO submarine simulator bundled with it.